# Регулярное выражение для MySQL RLIKE

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Написал регулярное выражение для поиска определенных слов внутри предложения:

```
(\s\.*)((объектив)|(зеркальный)) *(.*?)(\. )
```

= находит предложения, в которых есть слово "объектив" или "зеркальный".

И теперь мне нужно применить это регулярное выражение для поиска строк в базе данных mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM  `data` WHERE `description`  RLIKE  '(\s\.*)((".объектив)|(зеркальный)) *(.*?)(\. )'
```

**В ответ получаю:** Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Как я понял, нужно экранировать символы или менять на POSIX... Перепробовал кучу вариантов, ничего не получается. Помогите друзья, кто чем может!

Comment: @cheh1, скорее всего, это баг как в Oracle.  
Попробуйте так:  

    (\s\.*)((объектив)|(зеркальный)) *((.)*?)(\. )

Comment: А может, ваша задача решается полнотекстовым поиском?

Comment: @VenZell, не хочет! @ua6xh - возможно, напиши пример, пожалуйста, может, я на самом деле все усложняю!

Comment: @cheh1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Какая-то странная регулярка...  
Может, нужна такая?  

    \b(?:объектив|зеркальный)\b

Comment: @ReinRaus, насколько понял из вопроса, нужно захватить все предложение с этими словами, а не только сами слова.

Comment: @VenZell, в sql, насколько я знаю, нет никакого смысла захватывать текст в группы. Ведь захваченные группы нельзя нигде использовать.  
А выражение, которое использует ТС, не сработает на тексте:  

> Зеркальный объектив- это крутая штука! Купив его Вы сразу станете полупрофессиональным фотографом!

Если я ошибаюсь насчет захвата групп в SQL, поправьте меня, пожалуйста, буду признателен.

Comment: > А выражение, которое использует ТС, не сработает на тексте:
> Зеркальный объектив- это крутая штука!
> Купив его Вы сразу станете полупрофессиональным фотографом!

Его легко расширить, чтобы захватывало: http://regex101.com/r/pO8xR1/1

> Если я ошибаюсь насчет захвата групп в SQL, поправьте меня, 
> пожалуйста, буду признателен.

Об этом не подумал. Скорее всего вы правы, поскольку я не могу доказать обратное.

Comment: @cheh1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[@cheh1](/users/3104/cheh1), а вот так?

```
(\.)*(\s)*(([^.]*)((объектив)|(зеркальный))([^.]*))(\.)
```

Comment: Спасибо, @VenZell. Работает, как надо!